# do Something after AuthenticationProvider success in SpringSecurity

Tags: java, spring-security

I have multiple AuthenticationProviders(MyOwn, Kerberos, Local). I want to save some information with password after authentication success. But code after every provider is different. So I want to run this code right after authenticationProvider success. How can I do that?

If I use AuthenticationSuccessHandler it would run after any success from provider. If I write code inside CustomUserDetailsService, I can't reach password information inside it.

Answer (score 1):

You can register a listener for `AuthenticationSuccessEvent`.

The `ProviderManager` delegates authentication to each of it's registered `AuthenticationProvider`. After a successful authentication by one of the `AuthenticationProvider`, the `ProviderManager` will publish a `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` through it's `AuthenticationEventPublisher`.

If you want to receive this event and gain access to the `Authentication`, the following Java Configuration will register a `ApplicationListener` bean in the context for this event:

```
@Bean
public ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> authenticationSuccessEventListener() {
    return new ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent>() {

        @Override
        void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
                Authentication authentication = event.getAuthentication();
                // TODO
        }
    };
}
```

Further documentation for `ApplicationListener` can be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#context-functionality-events):